# Retrieve only selected simple product from configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, catalog

I currently have an extension that replaces the old product view page with a custom one, showing several configurable options, as the customer goes through the options it filters down to a simple product and they can purchase it

I currently have 3 links placed at the bottom of the page which are attributes (related to the simple products) but they only refer to the configurable product.

I have changed the following;

```
<?php if($_product->getPdfLink()){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getPdfLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/acrobat_reader_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($_product->getPsLink()){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getPsLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/photoshop_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($_product->getIndesignLink()){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getIndesignLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/indesign_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

To the following;

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){}
endif;
?>
<?php foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $simple_product->getPdfLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/acrobat_reader_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $simple_product->getPsLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/photoshop_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $simple_product->getIndesignLink();  ?>" target="_blank" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/indesign_25x25.gif'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

The code works, however it actually refers to all of the simple products related to the selected configurable...

How do I get it so it only shows the attributes related to the filtered simple product

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The simple product is selected by Javascript when the user select the options.
You cant send the Response for the selected simple product before the user select it. 
A good way to handle this is to trigger an AJAX Request to the Server and parse the options from that.

When all options are Selected and a simple Product is chosen, the Selected ProductID is in (as long as the original configurable_options template is used):

```
spConfig.config.productId
```